# Output Right Alignment

Tags: python, alignment, justify

```
output.write('{:>10}'.format(line[39:49]))
```

This is still providing me with a left justified output. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Right-justifying a string of length 10 within a field of width 10 doesn't seem to make too much sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take a random guess at what your problem might be.  Does

```
output.write('{:>10}'.format(line[39:49].strip()))
#                                       ^^^^^^^^
```

produce the desired output?